# Matlab transfer function model with variable gain dependent on 2 variables

Tags: matlab, controls

I am trying to model a simple first order system where the gain [image] is a function of 2 variables. The transfer function is below.

[image]

So, the model gain depends upon the values of [image] and [image] which will change with time.

How do I implment this in Matlab? I looked at the *tunableSurface* function but it normalises parameters which I don't want to do as they represent the sensitivity of a sensor, so normalising them is just unhelpful.

I don't think Matlab has the capability to do what I want, please tell me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are dealing with a linear analog system, you should be able to apply a time-invariant transfer function to your signal, i.e. 
[image]

and multiply the resulting signal with your time-varying weighting function afterwards. Changing this weighting function in the time domain should be quite straight-forward. 
If you were referring to a digital (sampled) signal, you might want to implement the convolution yourself. That will allow you to change the coefficients of your digital system on a sample to sample basis (and therefore give it a time-varying behavior)